# Отображение только букв на клавиатуре телефона

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-edittext

Всем привет.
Мне нужно отображать только буквы на клавиатуре. Без цифр и подсказок сверху. Нашёл команду, которая убирает подсказки сверху:

```
_editText.InputType = InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword | InputTypes.ClassText;
```

Но, как убрать ещё и цифры - не знаю

Пробовал ещё в layout пихать

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Но тоже никакой реакции

Comment: Никак, они вшиты в клаву, во всяком случае, у меня. Клавы разные бывают, зависит от вендора и версии андройда. На уровне Xamarin такой фичи точно нет.

Comment: Получается, остаётся только делать какую-то кастомную свою клавиатуру, которая будет без цифр? (не уверен, пока что, как это делать. просто вариант пришёл в голову)

Comment: не уверен что это хорошая идея. Многие печатают "жестами" и спасибо за кастомную клавиатуру они тебе точно не скажут)